# Como posso transformar um arquivo do tipo BLOB em uma imagem usando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, conversão-de-tipo, blob

Preciso transformar um arquivo BLOB que vem de um banco de dados MYSQL para o tipo Imagem, para usar em meu site, preciso fazer a conversão usando PHP, quando uso a imagem no formato BLOB, ela vai para o site toda em binário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem duas formas, uma é salvar o binário em arquivo (o que não é interessante) e outra é adicionar ao `src`da tag `img` informando que é um binário. Para fazer isso, basta adicionar `data:image/jpeg;base64,` seguido do código binário.

Ou seja:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($binary) ?>" />
```

Dependendo de como você salvou (em raros casos) o `base64_encode` pode ser omitido

Comment: Continua me trazendo a imagem em binário.

Comment: Se está aparecendo o código binário, há algo de errado na sua implementação. Usando o código acima, se a imagem não puder ser exibida, deve apresentar o ícone de "imagem quebrada" e não o código binário. Verifique se não existe algum apóstrofo que possa estar quebrando a tag `img`

Comment: É como o @GabrielHeming falou, usando a tag img você tinha que ver pelo menos uma imagem quebrada. Mas há uma ressalva, para a resposta dele, vc vai usar "image/jpeg" se vc sabe que o formato da imagem é esse? tem que saber também se o dado já não foi salvo como base64, neste caso não precisaria usar a função `base64_encode`.

Comment: A foto é jpeg e foi salva com o seguinte insert :insert into FOTOS_PRODUTOS (id,imagem) values (3,LOAD_FILE('/opt/lampp/htdocs/mvp/images/prod-top/terceira.jpg'))

Comment: Conferiu o HTML gerado para verificar se não há, ou falta, algum caracter?

Comment: como posso fazer essa conferência?